# Hide jquery UI bootstrap tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to hide the Jquery UI bootstrap tab
I have written code below to show the particular tab

```
 $('#myTab a:last').tab('show')
```

So i tried using below code to hide tab but it gives error that it has no method hide

```
 $('#myTab a:last').tab('hide')
```

I have declared tabs in following way in my html

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li><a href="#product" data-toggle="tab">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="#version" data-toggle="tab">Employee</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: do you want only last tab to be hidden, just try to use hide() and show() methods instead..

Comment: how to do it? Please explain. I want first tab to be closed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried `$('#myTab a:last').hide()` 
or 
`$('#myTab a:first').hide()` ?

Comment: Yes worked. Thanks a lot. Dont know why its not given in documentation on the website.

Comment: because it is not a part of bootstrap. I am simply using jquery methods to hide and show dom elements :)

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you could simply remove the `active` class from the elements instead:

```
$('.nav-tabs li.active').removeClass('active');
$('.tab-content div.active').removeClass('active');
```

This way you won't have any hidden elements that are still marked as `active`, which may interfere with other JS or CSS.

Comment: I us"ed" the hide fonction but when there are uls inside uls, your answer is veeery handy and elegant, thanks a lot cuz it really helped me

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to specially hide tab, you can just show the tab that you want and the other tab would automatically be hidden.
You can use :

```
$("a[href='#tabToBeShown']").tab("show");
```